# Need a Regex that can be applied on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters, repeat

I am looking for a regular expression in js where as it can accept anything say numbers,characters,special characters etc but no two or more consecutive special characters. Tried different combinations, but could not succeed.
for example:

```
abcd -- valid
abcd @ dfds -- valid
abcd#@ ssf  -- invalid
hi@try$example@test - valid
hi######hello  --- invalid
```

Comment: Reject 2 consecutive characters: 
    /^((\w)(?!\2))+$/i

Comment: @ avinash, tried /^\w[$,@,#]{2}*/. i am new to this and tried googling, but could not win.

Comment: @RIJINPK - You should put your attempt in your question.  Will help address the negative votes.

Comment: @NovaLogic, needs to reject only special characters that when they repeat twice or more consecutively.

Comment: @dustmouse, thanks for the info. i see more negative votes coming. but no problem, will try my best.

Comment: @RIJINPK - The main thing is to demonstrate that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I have given you a head start - the rest of the effort is on you. You're not likely to receive top-to-bottom solutions on SO. Try to do it yourself and if you can't then we'll address the issue. 

Read up on regex docs for instance: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

This `regExp` returns `true` for `hi######hello`, you can invert results as you like:

```
var regExp = /(?:.)*(?:[@$&#?]{2})+(?:.)*/g // @$&#? - your symbols go here  

regExp.test("hi######hello"); // true
regExp.test("hi@try$example@test"); // false
```